# Why i cant install the numpy package using pip on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python, numpy, installation, pip

Im trying to install the numpy package with python3 (python --version returns Python 3.5.2), but it doesnt work. Somebody can help me please with this problem? When i use the command

```
pip install numpy
```

, the terminal return to me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fabricio/.local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried install using Python2.7 but it was dreprecation

Answer (score 2):

You have, mysteriously, a version of pip that is using f-strings, such as `f"ERROR: {exc}"`, even though [f-strings were not introduced until Python 3.6](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). Furthermore, [recent versions of NumPy support Python 3.7 and above](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.20.x/setup.py).

Try installing a more recent version of Python3, activating a virtual environment, and installing with `python3 -m pip install numpy`.

Python 3.5 is also [EOL as of 2020-09-30](https://devguide.python.org/devcycle/#end-of-life-branches).